# A simple MySQL query help

Tags: mysql

Been stuck with this fairly simple MySQL query for a day now! Can't believe how quickly I've forgotten the basics. I have 3 tables - `user`, `post` and `favourite_post`. The post table has a user_id that is a FK to user table. 

The `favourite_post` table has

```
user_id REFERENCES user(id) 
post_id REFERENCES post(id)
timestamp
```

When a user favourites a post, his `user_id,` the `post_id` and `timestamp` are inserted into the favourite_post table.

I use the following query to retrieve the 15 more recent posts

```
SELECT post.id, post.text, post.timestamp, post.user_id, user.username 
FROM post 
   INNER JOIN user 
   ON post.user_id = user.id 
ORDER BY post.id 
DESC LIMIT 15;
```

What I need to do along with that is check if each post has been favourited by the current user(say user_id = 1) by joining with the favourite_post table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    SELECT p.id, p.text, p.timestamp, p.user_id, u.username, 
           IF(ISNULL(fp.post_id), 'No', 'Yes') has_favourite
      FROM post p
INNER JOIN user u
        ON p.user_id = u.id 
 LEFT JOIN favourite_post fp
        ON p.id = fp.post_id
       AND u.id = fp.user_id
  ORDER BY p.id DESC 
     LIMIT 15;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.id, p.text, fp.timestamp, p.user_id, u.username 
FROM post p INNER JOIN user u
    ON p.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN favourite_post fp
    ON fp.user_id = p.user_id AND fp.post_id = p.id
WHERE p.user_id = your_user_id
ORDER BY p.id DESC 
LIMIT 15;
```

Comment: Will not work as the "WHERE p.user_id = your_user_id" clause will make it match the posts made by the current user. The query by Shef works though.

Comment: @Checksum: you write _if each post has been favourited by the current user(say user_id = 1)_, so I thought I have to match using `WHERE` clause...